# Protractor getAttribute('value') returning as null

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm fairly new to Protractor and am having some difficulty in obtaining the text from an error box that displays only when a certain condition is met.

I am sure that it is just a syntax issue. Below is the line I am using to attempt to get the "text" that displays in the box, and compare it to a preset static string.

```
expect(element(by.css('[ng-switch-default=""]')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual(expected_error_message);
```

I am receiving the message back:

```
Message: Expected null to equal 'User with login test8827391@gmail.com' already exists.'
```

So basically there is nothing to compare strings against because the value that "getAttribute('value') is supposed to grab is returning null".

The block of HTML that I am referencing is found below:

```
<div ng-class="config.message" ng-switch="" on="toaster.bodyOutputType"         class="toast-message"><div ng-switch-default="" class="ng-binding">User with login  'test8827391@gmail.com' already exists.</div></div>
```

Comment: Attribute 'value' exists for input's. div's have text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your message is not an attribute, but the text for the div.
Try:

```
expect(element(by.css('[ng-switch-default=""]')).getText()).toEqual(expected_error_message);
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers and instead accompany you answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thought it was self evident since I just changed one thing, but I'll add some simple comments.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I knew that I had to just be looking at something wrong in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I have fallen to another hole. I accidentally selected label element, so sendKeys() method works, but getAttribute('value') has not.